# Gatsby codesandbox: TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gatsby

the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-o76zk

You can see that there is an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined. It seems having something to do with Gatsby-image`

I used this query to get the images

```
{
          allFile(
            filter: {
              extension: { regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/" }
              sourceInstanceName: { eq: "images" }
            }
          ) {
            edges {
              node {
                childImageSharp {
                  fluid {
                    ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                    originalImg
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

and the images are imported correctly and I console.log out the data that came from the query they all had the right shape like this and they do have a `src` prop

```
allFile: Object
edges: Array[5]
0: Object
node: Object
childImageSharp: Object
fluid: Object
base64: "data:image/..."
aspectRatio: 1
src: "/static/4a9773549091c227cd2eb82ccd9c5e3a/774d6/gatsby-icon.png"
srcSet: "/static/4a9773549091c227cd2eb82ccd9c5e3a/7c0ed/gatsby-icon.png 200w,
/static/4a9773549091c227cd2eb82ccd9c5e3a/647de/gatsby-icon.png 400w,
/static/4a9773549091c227cd2eb82ccd9c5e3a/774d6/gatsby-icon.png 512w"
sizes: "(max-width: 512px) 100vw, 512px"
originalImg: "/static/4a9773549091c227cd2eb82ccd9c5e3a/774d6/gatsby-icon.png"
```

You can inspect the console in the codesandbox link to see it.

I been really struggling to debug this and had no clue why this happened

Comment: I only can suggest you first try `Img` without using `Box` and if it doesn't work, then you could debug `Img`. But if it works, then it know you need to read some documentation of `Box`.

Comment: @windmaomao it appears to be a problem with `Box` because with `Img`(or Gatsby-image) there was no errors. but I been searching online for days and couldn't solve it

Comment: makes sense man, then you could open `Box` source code and debug there, because i don't think it can be very complex inside `Box`, should just be a wrapper sort of thing.